# Date drop down issue (formatting)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm creating a web app in Ruby on rails (cloud9) 
I have a Leave request option for the user
`date_leave`  and `date_return`

holiday controller:

```
require 'date'
```

holidays _form.html.err:

```
    <%= f.label :date_leave %><br>
    <%= f.date_select("date_leave", order: [:day,:month,:year]) %>

    <%= f.label :date_return %><br>
    <%= f.date_select("date_return", order: [:day,:month,:year]) %>
```

date listed:

```
{1=>2015, 2=>9, 3=>20}  {1=>2015, 2=>10, 3=>18}
```

and if i try to edit i get this error:

```
undefined method `year' for "{1=>2015, 2=>9, 3=>20}":String
```

Anyone any ideas on the issue?

```
class CreateHolidays < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :holidays do |t|
            t.string :booking_Id
            t.string :Employee_number
            t.string :leave_Request_Type
            t.string :date_leave
            t.string :date_return
            t.integer :total_days

            t.timestamps null: false
        end
    end
end

    def update
        respond_to do |format|
            if @holiday.update(holiday_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @holiday, notice: 'Leave request was successfully updated.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @holiday }
            else
                format.html { render :edit }
                format.json { render json: @holiday.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: Show us db migration for holidays & code for holidays#update action.

Comment: Your database columns for the dates need to be of type `date`, not `string`.

Comment: Yep that solve it. Thanks very much for your help. for anyone else with the same issue 'rake db:rollback'      edit your table and then migrate again 'rake:dbmigrate'